# Dispatching TinyFSM events from FreeRTOS queues

Tags: c++, state-machine, fsm

Hi I am trying to implement [TinyFSM](https://github.com/digint/tinyfsm) state machine in ESP32 embedded board project. I like TinyFSM simplicity, but I think it is useless without event queue. My previous experience with C/C++ state machine was with [QPC/C SM framework](https://github.com/QuantumLeaps/qpc), so I might tend to replicate QPC/C solutions in current project.

I started work with [TinyFSM example called SimpleSwitch](https://github.com/digint/tinyfsm/blob/master/examples/api/simple_switch.cpp)

My problem is: every fancy github FSM C++ library needs event type to be known at compile time while dispatching, so I made a simply mechanism delivering something which could be probably called handmade polymorphism or runtime type info: every event is dervied from base class and has certain event id and when the event is taken from freertos queue it is casted explicitly to it type and then dispatched. My current solution works, but its huge boilerplate and I guess I am doing something wrong here. How can I use event queues from Freertos and modern github stars legitimate library (as tinyfsm or boost-exp/sml) and avoid doing so much boilerplate?

Below I post my working code.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <esp_log.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/queue.h>

#include "net_sm.h"
#include "tinyfsm.hpp"

static const char *TAG = "net_sm";
static QueueHandle_t event_queue;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Event Declarations
//
enum class EvType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    TurnOn,
    TurnOff
};

struct Event : tinyfsm::Event 
{ 
    Event(EvType const type = EvType::Unknown) : _type{type} {}
    EvType _type {};
};

struct TurnOn : Event
{
    TurnOn() : Event(EvType::TurnOn) {};
    std::string message = "Turn on event";
};

struct TurnOff : Event
{
    TurnOff() : Event(EvType::TurnOff) {};
    std::string message = "Turn off event";
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2. State Machine Base Class Declaration
//
struct Switch : tinyfsm::MooreMachine<Switch>
{
  virtual void react(TurnOn const &) { 
    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Unhandled event TurnOn");
  };

  virtual void react(TurnOff const &) { 
    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Unhandlend event TurnOff");
  };
};


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 3. State Declarations
//
struct Off; // forward declaration

struct On : Switch
{
  void entry() override { std::cout << "* Closing ciruit (light goes ON)" << std::endl; };
  void react(TurnOff const &) override { 
    transit<Off>(); 
  };
};

struct Off : Switch
{
  void entry() override { std::cout << "* Opening ciruit (light goes OFF)" << std::endl; };
  void react(TurnOn const &) override { 
    transit<On>(); 
  };
};

FSM_INITIAL_STATE(Switch, Off)


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper functions
//
template <class T>
static void send_event(T * event)
{
    xQueueSend(event_queue, &event, 5 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

static void dispatch_que_event(void)
{
    Event * event_p = nullptr;
    if((pdTRUE == xQueueReceive(event_queue, &event_p, 0) && (event_p != nullptr)))
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Dispatch event id: %d", (int)event_p->_type);

        switch(event_p->_type){
            case EvType::TurnOn: {
                auto event = reinterpret_cast<TurnOn *>(event_p);
                Switch::dispatch(*event);
            }
            break;
            case EvType::TurnOff: {
                auto event = reinterpret_cast<TurnOff *>(event_p);
                Switch::dispatch(*event);
            }
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        delete(event_p);
    }
}

static void dispatch_task(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dispatch_que_event();
    vTaskDelay(50 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

int main_test()
{
    event_queue = xQueueCreate(50, sizeof(void *));

    Switch::start();

    auto turn_on_message = new TurnOn();
    send_event(turn_on_message);
    auto turn_off_message = new TurnOff();
    send_event(turn_off_message);
    send_event(new TurnOff());

    xTaskCreate(dispatch_task, "dispatch_task", 2048, NULL, 12, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try QP/C directly? I mean, why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @MiroSamek I would love to use QP/C or QP/CPP, you did a great work and we used your library hard in my previous job, but now I work elsewhere and here your library purchase won't go through